# Slider works on localhost and doesn't work on github

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Can't understand how to fix these errors with slider.
On computer everything works great but when I pushed it on github it crushed

[Link to slider](https://cdn.rawgit.com/Annelia55/Sweet-recepies/master/Index.html)

[image: Image with error]

Comment: This can be due to a an expired certificate on the server you are requesting your resources. 

Try to load them with http

Comment: Can you explain it in more details? Didn't catch it

Comment: All the requests are `https` - you are trying to get resources with a secure protocol, but the answer from the server is not secure. You need to make `http` requests instead of `https` - or configure the site certificate properly.